# CSS :selectors animation stops working correctly after removing "required" tag from input field

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, css-transforms

I have the following code, which move the label out of the input field, as soon as the input is focused or valid.

```css
.form-control-placeholder {
  font-family: "Zuric Light";
  color: black;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  padding: 7px 0 0 13px;
  transition: all 200ms;
  opacity: .5;
}

.form-control:focus + .form-control-placeholder,
.form-control:valid + .form-control-placeholder {
  padding: 0;
  transform: translate3d(0, -100px, 0);
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" id="address2" class="form-control" name="address2" required>
    <label class="form-control-placeholder" for="address2">Address line 2</label>
</div>
```

As you might see, the `required` attribute is applied to the `input` field. But as soon as I remove it, it stops working correctly because of the `:valid` selector. Without the `required` attribute, it will be valid all the time.

How do I solve this and can this be achieved with solely CSS?

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue on a snippet, it works on my side. Please make a [mcve] ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`:valid` works only if the `input` have `required` attribute. Other way to achieve this is using [`:placeholder-shown`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:placeholder-shown) Pseudo class.

This pseudo class select all `input` and `textarea` that currently shows the *placeholder text*. In order to work, the input element must have the `placeholder` attribute.

> According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:placeholder-shown#Browser_compatibility), MS Edge won't support this.

In this case, You want the `label` to go up only when input is focussed or it contains some value. So you need to use `:not(:placeholder-shown)` instead of `:placeholder-shown`. Otherwise it'll produce inverse effect.

```css
div{
position: absolute;
width:100%;
top:50px;
}
.form-control-placeholder {
  font-family: "Zuric Light";
  color: black;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  padding: 7px 0 0 13px;
  transition: all 200ms;
  opacity: .5;
}

.form-control:focus+.form-control-placeholder,
.form-control:not(:placeholder-shown)+.form-control-placeholder {
  padding: 0;
  transform: translate3d(0, -100%, 0);
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <input type="text" id="address2" class="form-control" ngModel name="address2" placeholder="...">
  <label class="form-control-placeholder" for="address2">Address line 2</label>
</div>
```

Comment: The text shall stay above the input as soon it's filled.

Comment: Hi @Tim , I just came out for lunch and on my mobile now.Will look into it soon.

Comment: Hi @Tim, The input element doesn't have placeholder, which I missed earlier. The selector works based on placeholder text and input must contain the placeholder attribute. I updated the code